# How do I create a URL slug extension?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a blog application using [Spring](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) and [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/). For each article, I need to programmatically generate a slug. For example, if the article title is "How the Chihuahua Crossed the Road", the slug should be "how-the-chihuahua-crossed-the-road".

For context, my entity file (truncated) looks something like:

```
@Entity
class Article(
    var title: String,
    var slug: String = I_WANT_THIS_TO_BE_A_SLUG_FROM_THE_TITLE)
```

How do I accomplish this with a Kotlin extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Extensions.kt` file, add the following code:

```
fun String.toSlug() = toLowerCase()
        .replace("\n", " ")
        .replace("[^a-z\\d\\s]".toRegex(), " ")
        .split(" ")
        .joinToString("-")
        .replace("-+".toRegex(), "-")
```

Then use the extension in your entity file:

```kotlin
@Entity
class Article(
    var title: String,
    var slug: String = title.toSlug())
```

Additionally, if you don't want the slug to be mutable, add it as a calculated property:

```kotlin
@Entity
class Article(
        var title: String) {
    val slug get() = title.toSlug()
}
```

### References

I learned about the slug extension from [Building web applications with Spring Boot and Kotlin](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/#_creating_your_own_extensions) (written by [Sébastien Deleuze](https://github.com/sdeleuze)). See the [Extensions.kt lines 28 - 33](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/example/blog/Extensions.kt#L28) for full context.

Also, thanks to [Dave Leeds](https://github.com/djleeds) for recommending the calculated property option. Checkout his Kotlin blog [Dave Leeds on Kotlin](https://typealias.com/) for in-depth concepts and guides.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with all explanations

```
import java.text.Normalizer

fun String.slugify(): String = Normalizer
                .normalize(this, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                .replace("[^\\w\\s-]".toRegex(), "") // Remove all non-word, non-space or non-dash characters
                .replace('-', ' ') // Replace dashes with spaces
                .trim() // Trim leading/trailing whitespace (including what used to be leading/trailing dashes)
                .replace("\\s+".toRegex(), "-") // Replace whitespace (including newlines and repetitions) with single dashes
                .toLowerCase() // Lowercase the final results
```

I created a gist https://gist.github.com/raychenon/8fac7e5fb41364694f00e6ce8b8c32a8